# what are the actions facebook allow while user is offline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, offline

i am making a new facebook application in which user uses internet only for approve permissions of my fb application.After that  the user will be offline.so i need to know what are the actions facebook allow me to perform while user is offline

Comment: There's no different between offline or online, on access token conceptual